# NullPointer Exception when decrypting AES

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I was able to successfully encrypt a message with a generated key. Now I am trying to achive decryption whereby a user would enter a key (hex) and there encrypted message (hex). I am having a problem when decrypting the the encrypted message (hex). I receive multiple NullPointerExceptions. Could you possible help me figure out a solution to this problem please?

//Edit: For Example the key (Hex): CFDD0F5311764F9EA56CF4126E304BC2
| Encrypted Message: C2A80A2B7A84A5A785E059F19322E5BA

```
private void executeDecryption() {
    encryptMessageStr = messageEncryptTA.getText();
    algorithmType = decryptAlgorithmTypeCB.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    keyDecrypt = keyTF.getText();

    if (!messageEncryptedTA.getText().isEmpty()) {

        try {
            //Using decryptText()
            String textDecipher = decryptText(encryptedMessageStr, keyDecrypt);
            messageEncryptedTA.setText(textDecipher);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.display("Error!", "Could not decrypt message! Please try again later");
            //System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    } else {
        MessageBox.display("Warning!", "Please make sure message field is not empty!");
    }
}

public static String decryptText(String encryptedMessageStr, String secretKey) {
    try {
        Key k = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(secretKey), "AES");
        Cipher cipherAES = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipherAES.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);

        byte[] decodedValue = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedMessageStr);
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = cipherAES.doFinal(decodedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(cipherTextBytes);
        return decryptedValue;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "Error";

}
```

**Edited:**

EXCEPTION:
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Answer (score 0):

Without any context or line numbers it is difficult to pinpoint the exact problem. You should check where in your code the exception is thrown and why the variable you're trying to access is null. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) question, as suggested by Simze

According to the  [Base64.Decoder documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html),

> Unless otherwise noted, passing a null argument to a method of this class will cause a NullPointerException to be thrown.

So you are somehow passing a null String reference to the decode method.

Comment: Hello, I have added some edits to the Null pointer Exceptions.

Comment: Your mostlikely correct. The problem is the fact that I am taking in a hex value when I supossed to be taking a plain text. Any ideas on how i can covert the hex into bytes?

Comment: How do I convert a string(hex) to the seceret key?